# how to redirect to another view from view in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I've written below code for login view in ASP.NET Core MVC:

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
    Layout = null;

}
<head>
</head>
<body>
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("User")))
    {
        //redirect to home page
    }
    <div class="main">
        <p class="sign" align="center">Sign in</p>
        <form class="form1" asp-action="Login" asp-controller="User" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input class="un" type="text" align="center" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">
            <input class="pass" type="password" align="center" placeholder="Password" name="Password" id="password">
            <input type="submit" class="submit" align="center" value="Sign in" id="signIn">
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
</body>
```

If `Session` contains data for key `User`

- then I don't want to show Login page
- instead I want to redirect the page to `Index` action of the `HomeController`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way but javascript to do that. This is because the view is rendering step of current request, you can not return redirect action. Also this is not good logic for MVC concept.

**with javascript:**

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("User")))
{
    //redirect to home page
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index","HomeController")";
    </script>
}
```

But I suggest you to achive it in your login controller. Before returning your action result, check if **User** exists in session, then redirect if required.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me, also is there any other correct way to do that in asp.net core?

Comment: You can return [RedirectToAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) result in your controller